# Disable iOS dynamic type in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to disable text getting enlarged by iOS dynamic type when developing in Flutter?

I have a few aesthetic Texts used in stacks with images that get screwed up when the text gets enlarged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Enclose the Widget with this, it will disable its dynamic typing, recursively.

```
return MediaQuery(
  child: your-widget-here,
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work on GoogleMap widget. The location name of the map still change when the global device text size setting has change.